# Module not found: Package path . is not exported from package

Tags: javascript, firebase, visual-studio-code, terminal, next.js

ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

I got the following error(s) in my code when trying to connect with Firebase.

File: **firebase.js**

Code:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase"

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "***",
  authDomain: "***",
  projectId: "***",
  storageBucket: "***",
  messagingSenderId: "***",
  appId: "***",
};

const app = !firebase.apps.length
  ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  : firebase.app();

const db = app.firestore();
const auth = app.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export { db, auth, provider };
```

Error(s):

```
Module not found: Package path . is not exported from package <project location>\node_modules\firebase (see exports field in <project location>\node_modules\firebase\package.json)
Did you mean './firebase'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.
> 1 | import * as firebase from "firebase";
  2 |
  3 | const firebaseConfig = {
  4 |   apiKey: "***",

Import trace for requested module:
./pages\_app.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

File: **./pages_app.js**

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { auth, db } from "../firebase";
import Login from "./login";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

  if (!user) return <Login />;

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your firebase import to:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase"
```

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.

Comment: I updated the Code and Error(s) to what I changed it to.

Comment: Also, I added the contents of **_app.js**

Comment: one of your issues here could be that you have named the file firebase.js as well. you might try and change it to firebase-handler or something. also, are you using this firebase npm package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `'firebase'` to `'./firebase'` as indicated in the error message

Comment: I got another error : /

Comment: What was the new error ? Also be careful, the import changed for the last firebase version to this: 
`import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69613217/typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-firebase

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issues. What you need to  do is to call

`import * as firebase from "firebase/app"`

instead of `import * as firebase from "firebase"`.

Also, if you are  trying to  use all functions such as `GoogleAuthProvider`,
you have to  import it as  follows

`import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";`

I  hope this helps.