# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js

I am trying to connect to Firebase.

Code from firebase.js:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/compat/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "***",
  authDomain: "***",
  projectId: "***",
  storageBucket: "***",
  messagingSenderId: "***",
  appId: "***",
};

const app = !firebase.apps.length
  ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  : firebase.app();

const db = app.firestore();
const auth = app.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export { db, auth, provider };
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please consider not including sensitive/confidential information.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Lastly, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Also, take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing imports for Firestore (as the error mentions) and Authentication.

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

Also see the documentation on [updating imports to v9 compat](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat).

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment on your other thread, firebase imports have changed recently. Try to change `fribase` to `firebase/compat/app`
[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#window-compat)

Comment: hey, could you help me again lol

Comment: it says _**TypeError: app.firestore is not a function**_

Comment: try to import `firebase/compat/app` instead. Also in your comments code, I believe that "auth" is from `firebase/auth` not `fribase`. `db` should not be in brackets

Answer (score 0):

Just coming across this, I hope this solution helps:
simply upgrade "firebase" to version: "^9.4.0"

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "*********************",
authDomain: "**************.com",
projectId: "*********",
storageBucket: "**************",
messagingSenderId: "***********",
appId: "**********************"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(app);//access to the database
const auth = getAuth(); //access to the authentication
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider(); //access tp the provider

export { db, auth, provider };
```